# Installing Python 3.3 on Cygwin

Tags: python, python-3.x, cygwin, installation, python-3.3

I'm having trouble installing Python 3.3 on Cygwin. I've tried installing from source, but `make` returns:

```
gcc -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes     -I. -IInclude -I./Include    -DPy_BUILD_CORE  -c ./Modules/signalmodule.c -o Modules/signalmodule.o
In file included from Include/Python.h:84:0,
                 from ./Modules/signalmodule.c:6:
./Modules/signalmodule.c: In function `fill_siginfo':
./Modules/signalmodule.c:745:60: error: `siginfo_t' has no member named `si_band'
     PyStructSequence_SET_ITEM(result, 6, PyLong_FromLong(si->si_band));
                                                            ^
Include/tupleobject.h:62:75: note: in definition of macro `PyTuple_SET_ITEM'
 #define PyTuple_SET_ITEM(op, i, v) (((PyTupleObject *)(op))->ob_item[i] = v)
                                                                           ^
./Modules/signalmodule.c:745:5: note: in expansion of macro `PyStructSequence_SET_ITEM'
     PyStructSequence_SET_ITEM(result, 6, PyLong_FromLong(si->si_band));
     ^
Makefile:1501: recipe for target `Modules/signalmodule.o' failed
make: *** [Modules/signalmodule.o] Error 1
Makefile:1501: recipe for target 'Modules/signalmodule.o' failed
make: ***[Modules/signalmodule.o] error 1
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show the text before that? All it says is that some command failed, but we need to see the commands.

Comment: Cygwin's Python packages include a number of patches; I suggest using the 3.2 patchset and `.cygport` as a basis for working on 3.3.

Comment: @Yaakov, I'm not really sure what you're referring to or how to execute it. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @DavidY.Stephenson Yaakov is referring to the standard way to add external python packages to cygwin.  Go to http://cygwinports.org to see the basic information.

Comment: What is the motivation for using Cygwin? The official distribution for Windows is excellent.

Comment: I find working in a Windows environment exceptionally cumbersome. While the Windows Python distribution is quite good, I would still have to work in Windows. Fortunately, I am no longer working with Cygwin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building Python on Cygwin is not trivial -- I tried.  However, the Python community on its bug tracker website is unusually friendly and gentle for a project its size and importance.  If you find specific issues, open bugs and follow the discussion.  Usually, they will accept tiny patches to fix Cygwin build issues.

[This patch](https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-packages/blob/master/python3/3.3.2-cygwin-siginfo.patch) will solve your first problem about `si->si_band`.  See related Python issue [#21085](http://bugs.python.org/issue21085).

[This blog post](https://www.hartmutpfarr.de/cygwin_python_3_4) (in German) is amazing.  It will walk you through step-by-step how to build Python3.4 and fix all Cygwin issues.

Good luck.  You will need it.