# Is latest Python (3.4 or later) available with cygwin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cygwin, python-3.4

I want to use the cygwin installer to get a newer version of python3. I downloaded the latest cygwin setup tool (x86 32 bit) from http://cygwin.com/install.html. When I look at packages to install, the current python3 is listed as `3.2.3-1` and I already have this version installed.

Edit: I checked https://cygwin.com/packages/ and it appears that 3.2 is indeed the latest version available. If I can't use the cygwin installer, is there a way to get python3.4 on my cygwin file system that isn't too hacky?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today, you're stuck. I only see 3.2 as well. There's nothing stopping you from building/installing a later python into Cygwin as you would into any other *nix.

There was some chatter, but no answer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767142/installing-python-3-3-on-cygwin) about installing python 3.3 into Cyg that may get you started.

**Edit (June 2015)** Python 3.4.3 is now available via cygwin package installer.